# "Fatal error when title field is empty(Integrity constraint violation)"

Tags: null, title, drupal-content-types

I am getting the error above whenever I try to save content on my drupal 10 site. The rest of the error message is below. How do I resolve this? I have created a slideshow and aside from a few initial slides that were saved, I am no longer able to add and save content for the slideshow without getting the fatal error referenced above.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code.